# Programmatically deposit funds into a Steam Wallet?

Tags: reverse-engineering, steam

Does anyone know if it is possible to programmatically deposit funds into a user's Steam wallet? Ideally I would like to issue some call where a User A pays for funds to be deposited into a User B's wallet. I've looked through the Steam API and didn't see anything relevant, but am curious whether or not I might have missed something. Thanks.